# Asking DNS server for record and checking authoritative

Tags: java, dns, dnsjava

How can I ask DNS server e.g 8.8.8.8 for google.com domain? On this http://www.xbill.org/dnsjava/dnsjava-current/examples.html page is example how can you send request for specified domain, but how can ask concrete server and check if answer is authoritative? I can use dnsjava or another Java lib

Answer (score 5):

To do request to the particular server you may use dnsjava with org.xbill.DNS.SimpleResolver configured:

```
    Resolver resolver = new SimpleResolver("10.233.104.38");
    Lookup lookup = new Lookup("google.com", Type.A);
    lookup.setResolver(resolver);
    Record[] records = lookup.run();
    String address = ((ARecord) records[0]).getAddress().toString();
    System.out.println(address);
```